# Avoid multiple login using the same user name and password

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing multiple browser sessions on the same server session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178604/preventing-multiple-browser-sessions-on-the-same-server-session)

I am developing an application that needs to prevent multiple login using the same user name and password.

If it happens on the same machine then obviously we need to do something with the user session, but it should also prevent if they are login on different machines using the same user name and password.

We have to keep following things in mind:

If user close the browser without logout.
If session time out.
I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your db that is 0 or 1

in your logic for login part of your app check against this field, if its 0 logon and then switch to 1.. On logout swith back to 0... And can't login unless 0.

Comment: which would mean, if a user logs in and closes the browser - they can't login again ever

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of database or a file saved on the sever, and there you can set a flag if a user is logged in or not, combined with the session id.

You can set a timeout (a last-active) for the flag, so that a new user can log in (if the old user has been idle or closes the browser without logout).
Then u can update the last-active on user-interactions or even with an ajax script.

Comment: can you provide any sample script or code to do this.

Comment: There must be plenty of it.. e.g. http://www.post1.net/biow/entry/simple_php_login_code_example